# Laravel- redirect with variable and display it in the view file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{if ($request->input('asc')){
                $image = PropertyUser::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
                foreach($image as $property)
                {
                    $id = $property->property_id;
                }
                $image_ = Image::where('property_id', $id)->sortBy('description')->get();
                return redirect('settings/photos');
```

How can i redirect with the `$image_` variable and display it in my view file

```
@foreach ($image_ as $images)
            <div class="image-warp"><img src="{{$images->filename}}"
                                         style="width:100px;height:100px;"><br/><span style="color: #1b1e21">{{$images->description}}</span>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Read the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{if ($request->input('asc')){
                $image = PropertyUser::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
                foreach($image as $property)
                {
                    $id = $property->property_id;
                }
                $image_ = Image::where('property_id', $id)->sortBy('description')->get();
                return view('yourfolder.yourviewfile',compact('image_'));
```

**Updated Answer**

```
use Redirect;

public function store(Request $request)
{if ($request->input('asc')){
                $image = PropertyUser::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
                foreach($image as $property)
                {
                    $id = $property->property_id;
                }
                $image_ = Image::where('property_id', $id)->sortBy('description')->get();

                Redirect::to('settings/photos?image_='. $image_);
```

Comment: it returns back with a blank page

Comment: please display your code after update with my answer

Comment: if ($request->input('asc')){
                    $image = PropertyUser::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
                    foreach($image as $property)
                    {
                        $id = $property->property_id;
                    }
                    $image_ = Image::where('property_id', $id)->sortBy('description')->get();
                    return redirect('settings.photos', compact('image_'));

Comment: @AdokiyeIruene: Please replace `return redirect('settings.photos', compact('image_'));` to  `return view('settings.photos', compact('image_'));`

Comment: it's still blank

Comment: @AdokiyeIruene: Your view file in settings folder right means your path like `yourproject/resources/views/settings/photos.blade.php`

Comment: Yes, i even have a create method before the store method

Comment: public function create()
    {
         dd(Input::get('asc'));
        $image = PropertyUser::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        foreach($image as $property)
        {
            $id = $property->property_id;
        }
        $image_main = Image::where('property_id', $id)->get();
        return view('settings.photos', ['image_array' => $image_main]);
    }

Comment: @AdokiyeIruene: This `store()` method is post method?

Comment: Yes, the store method is post method

Comment: @AdokiyeIruene: Please check my updated answer and please try with updated answer and let me know it's work for you or not

Answer (score 7):

You can also send variable using below syntax also

```
return view('viewfile')->with('card',$card)->with('another',$another);
```

You can send data using redirect method. Those data will store inside Session Class.

```
return redirect('url')->with('message',$message);
```

like below

```
Session::get('variableName');
Session::get('message');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the compact function to pass it to your view and reference it by the name.

```
return redirect('folder.name', compact('variableName');
return redirect()->route('folder.name', [$image]);
```

Comment: it returns back with a blank page

Comment: Sorry try pointing to a route
    return redirect()->route('/images', [$image]);

Answer (score 3):

you can try with below code

```
        return view('settings/photos')->with(['image' =>  $image_]);
```

Comment: it returns back with a blank page

Comment: from above line I have given here a demo page address.
place your page address instead of  ('settings/photos').

then in that page check with <?php dd($image);?> you may get all images data

Answer (score 2):

Send an array of variables to your view:

```
return view('folder.viewfile', array(
    'image_' => $image_,
    'someother_variable' => $somevar,
));
```

Comment: it returns back with a blank page

Comment: What is the name of your view? And where is it stored? Kindly replace the path in the above code. In the example above, the path is `/resources/views/folder/viewfile.blade.php` so in the controller it becomes `folder.viewfile`

Answer (score 2):

Why you're using variable like this $image_ , you can use it simply like this $image or $whatEver

```
return view('folder.viewfile', compact('image'));
```

And now you can use this variable on view file as $image.

Comment: It returns back with a blank page

Comment: Hey Adokiye lruene,
I think your query

Image::where('property_id', $id)->sortBy('description')->get()

It is not working properly,
Can you please show me, what its return?

Answer (score 2):

Do that in your controller function:

```
$request->session()->flash('order_id', $order_id);
```

And in view simply:

```
{{Session::get('order_id')}}
```

Answer (score 1):

i just found myself in the same proble and solve with the help of you guys :) 
on a complet example mi code ended like this:
mi FormCreate.php view recive an id from the previus page , so the url with out mask is "FormumariosCreate/16" in this example where the id is = 16 :

form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('FormulariosStore2', $Formularios->idFormularios ) }}"> // is importan add the id on the rute 
          @csrf

<input type="text" name="textoPregunta" required="required" />

<button href="" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Crear Nueva Pregunta</button>
</form>
```

rute in web.php:

```
Route::get('/FormulariosStore2/{idFormularios}', 'HomeController@FormulariosStore2')->name('FormulariosStore2');
Route::post('/FormulariosStore2/{idFormularios}', 'HomeController@FormulariosStore2')->name('FormulariosStore2');
```

and controler:

```
   public function FormulariosStore2(Request $request,$id )
    {
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
'textoPregunta' => 'required|max:255',
     ]);

$ProyectoPreguntasF=ProyectoPreguntas::create($validatedData);

$Formularios = Formularios::findOrFail($id); 

return redirect()->route('FormulariosCreate', $Formularios)->with('success','la operacion fue correcta.');
    }
```

then it redirect to the rute "FormulariosCreate" with the id as a normal link with the id ,i hope it can add some content to the answer